# unique working incorrectly with data.table

Tags: r, unique, data.table

I've discovered some interesting behavior in data.table, and I'm curious if someone can explain to me why this is happening.  I'm merging two data.tables (in this MWE, one has 1 row and the other 2 rows).  The merged data.table has two unique rows, but when I call unique() on the merged data.table, I get a data.table with one row.  Am I doing something wrong?  Or is this a bug?

Here's an MWE:

```
library(data.table)
X = data.table(keyCol = 1)
setkey(X, keyCol)
Y = data.table(keyCol = 1, otherKey = 1:2)
setkeyv(Y, c("keyCol", "otherKey"))
X[Y, ] # 2 unique rows
unique(X[Y, ]) # Only 1 row???
```

I'd expect unique(X[Y, ]) to be the same as X[Y, ] since all rows are unique, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Check `attr(X[Y], "sorted")`. It is keyed by `keyCol` so this is what `unique` uses. Try then `Y[X]` and then check `attr(Y[X], "sorted")` and you'll figure it out.

Comment: So if two rows have different values but the same key, one will be removed by data.table:::unique.data.table?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but actually you should check keys just with `key(X[Y])` and `key(Y[X])`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I'm still a bit confused...  What does Y[X, ] have to do with this problem?  I know that Y has more keys than X, but I don't understand why unique(X[Y, ]) will "de-duplicate" two rows with the same key but with different values.

Comment: Read `?unique`, especially the `by` argument.

Comment: @Arun: thanks, that makes sense.  If you want to write that as an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value to `by` argument for `unique.data.table` is `key(x)`. Therefore, if you do `unique(x)` on a keyed data.table, it only looks at the key columns. To override it, do:

```
unique(x, by = NULL)
```

`by = NULL` by default considers all the columns. Alternatively you can also provide `by = names(x)`.

Comment: At least since version 1.10, unique seems to default to uniqueness by all columns for data.table https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/11e6497b6ebf209c2376a20c0891e52e191bd96f